# How to test cell coordinates in Python to change data?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to use python to migrate some data. I need to test see if I have specific column, then if cell value is one value, change to specific other value. So my problem is, how to do test for coordinate.

I am using python and excel. I need to read in excel file, then make changes to data, and output new, changed excel file.
I'm using Python and PyCharm and now trying with openpyxl. I tried xlrd/xlwt, and tried doing with csv. To take data from sql to excel file, then make changes - this seemed to be easiest way to do.

So for instance, in specific case, I have in column 4 field for sex. So I try to specify only column 4 then. Old data has values either "Male" or "Female" new data needs to be numeric code, 1 for Male and 2 for Female.

```
    for cellObj in row:
     if cellObj.coordinate == [4:row]:
        if cellObj.value == 'Male':
            cellObj.value = 1
        elif cellObj.value == 'Female':
            cellObj.value = 2
```

(Sorry, I try to make format for question right, but code doesn't show the same.)

This code is not right. I don't understand how to do this. I have book Automate The Boring Stuff With Python by Al Sweigart. I have been looking in forums and blogs, but always you must know the exact coordinates. That's why I try with specific column 4 rather than testing in code to see which column I need.

EDIT:

I could not add to commant. Here is all code. Only getting 1 row now.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_location)
sheet = wb.worksheets[0]
for cellObj in sheet.rows[0]:
  print(cellObj.value),
  print(' | '),
for row in sheet.iter_rows():
  for row_count, cellObj in enumerate(row):
      if cellObj.coordinate == 'E{}'.format(row_count):
          print row_count
          print(cellObj.value),
          if cellObj.value == 'Male':
             cellObj.value = 1
             print(cellObj.value)
          elif cellObj.value == 'Female':
             cellObj.value = 2
             print(cellObj.value)
```

I added and change sheet.iter_rows....This here: [OpenPyXL + How can I search for content in a cell in Excel, and if the content matches the search criteria update the content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205863/openpyxl-how-can-i-search-for-content-in-a-cell-in-excel-and-if-the-content-m)
But this doesn't work either. On for loop, I can't do:

```
for i in sheet:
   do this for each row "i"
```

This format does not work?

Also, here: [OpenPyXL + How can I search for content in a cell in Excel, and if the content matches the search criteria update the content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205863/openpyxl-how-can-i-search-for-content-in-a-cell-in-excel-and-if-the-content-m)
Someone said can do sheet.rows() to go through each row, but this gives the tuple error again.
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

After your update, this seems to be a better solution:

```
for row in sheet.iter_rows():
    for cellObj in row:
        if cellObj.column == 'E':
             # do something
```

**Old answer**

Coordinates are in the form `A1`. You need to test against something like this:

```
for row_count, cellObj in enumerate(row, 1):
    if cellObj.coordinate == 'D{}'.format(row_count):
```

Comment: Okay thank you for that Mike Müller. I think I was trying to make like Python array. Excel seems to work differently. I understand. My code did work, but I can't seem to move through rows. It only gives me first row. For loop does not seem to work as I would expect it. Here is

Comment: Perfect! That was I was looking for. Thank you again! I have it now working how I expect and want.