# Python 3 openpyxl finding all of string in column

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am just starting to learn python and am looking for some direction on a script I am working on to text out daily pick up for my drivers. The vendor name is entered into a spreadsheet along with a purchase order # and notes. What i would like to do is cycle through column "A", find all instances of a vendor name, grab the corresponding B & C cell values and save all info to a text file. I can get it to work if I name the search string explicitly but not if its a variable. Here is what I have so far:

```
TestList=[]
TestDict= {}
LineNumber = 0
for i in range(1, maxrow + 1):
    VendorName = sheet.cell(row = i, column = 1)
    if VendorName.value ==  "CERTIFIED LETTERING":#here is where im lost
    #print (VendorName.coordinate)
    VendLoc = str(VendorName.coordinate)
    TestList.append(VendLoc)
    TestDict[VendorName.value]=[TestList]
    test = (TestDict["CERTIFIED LETTERING"][0])
    ListLength = (len(test))
    ListPo = []
    List_Notes = []
    number = 0
    for i in range (0, ListLength):
        PO = (str('B'+ test[number][1]))
        Note = (str('C'+ test[number][1]))
        ListPo.append(PO)
        List_Notes.append(Note)

        number = number + 1
    number = 0
    TestVend =(str(VendorName.value))
    sonnetFile = open('testsaveforpickups.txt', 'w')
    sonnetFile.write("Pick up at:" + '\n')
    sonnetFile.write(str(VendorName.value)+'\n')
    for i in range (0, ListLength):
        sonnetFile.write ("PO# "+ str(sheet[ListPo[number]].value)+'\n'
               +"NOTES: " + str(sheet[List_Notes[number]].value)+'\n')
        number = number + 1 
    sonnetFile.close()
```

the results are as follows:

```
Pick up at:
CERTIFIED LETTERING
PO# 1111111-00
NOTES: aaa
PO# 333333-00
NOTES: ccc
PO# 555555-00
NOTES: eee
```

I've tried everything i could think of to change the current string of "CERTIFIED LETTERING" to a variable name, including creating a list of all vendors in column A and using that as a dictionary to go off of. Any help or ideas to point me in the right direction would be appreciated. And I apologise for any formatting errors. I'm new to posting here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String/regex search over Excel in Python issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37033451/string-regex-search-over-excel-in-python-issue)

Comment: As it stands now it is unclear what you are asking.  Would be much better if you your data and what you are trying to make it look like.